# Python imaplib doesnt mark messages as unseen

Tags: python, imaplib

I am working on a function that collects data from email and has a switch to mark messages as unseen. During development it started to fail I don't know why. I've looked it up in documentation, I've searched stackoverflow (got to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367611/python-imaplib-mark-email-as-unread-or-unseen) thread, but it didn't help). Anyway. This is the code:

```
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', '993')
    mail.login(settings.INVOICES_LOGIN, settings.INVOICES_PASSWORD)
    mail.select('inbox')

    result, data = mail.uid('search', '(UNSEEN)', 'X-GM-RAW',
                            'SUBJECT: "{0}" FROM: "{1}"'.format(attachment_subject, attachment_from))
    uids = data[0].split()
    for uid in uids:
        result, data = mail.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)')
        m = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

        if m.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            for part in m.walk():
                if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                    continue
                if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                    continue
                if re.match(attachment_filename_re, part.get_filename()):
                    attachments.append({'uid': uid, 'data': part.get_payload(decode=True)})

        if set_not_read:
            mail.store(uid, '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')
```

I've debugged it, I am sure that with this flag the `mail.store(uid, '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')` part is entered, I've also tried switching to `\SEEN` and `\Seen` instead of (\Seen).

EDIT:

What I'm trying to do is to make a script that allows user to mark email as `unseen` (not read), this is reset the `Seen` flag, and not to allow it to mark an email as `seen` (read).

Comment: Working with `imaplib` myself just recently, I can confirm the state of SO questions is pretty pitiful.

Comment: What's the output of `mail.store(uid, '-FLAGS', '(\\SEEN)')`?

Comment: No, it just won't work.

Comment: "won't work" - does that mean that it produces an error? Produces nothing? Because `mail.store` *should* be producing a result. You can do `print(mail.store(uid, '-FLAGS', '(\\SEEN)')` and it should produce *something*, even if that something is a traceback. If nothing at all happens then something very strange is happening.

Comment: I mean the result is a tuple ('OK', [None]) and the mail in the mailbox remains marked as read.

Comment: When you get the flags - `print(mail.fetch(uid, '(FLAGS)'))` right after you call store, what is the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119022/discussion-between-wayne-werner-and-wiktor-gonczaronek).

Comment: You are only searching for UNSEEN messages, so they are already unseen.  Use FETCH BODY.PEEK[] so they don't get marked seen.

Comment: @WayneWener That may have more to do with the fact that imaplib is a very thin protocol library, and does not do any parsing work.  It assumes you already know RFC 3501 and email standards.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want

```
mail.store(uid, '+FLAGS', '(\\Seen)')
```

I think what you're doing right now is *removing* the seen flag. But I'll look in the RFC to be sure.

**Edit:** Yup. That's what the [RFC says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-59)

```
-FLAGS <flag list>
         Remove the argument from the flags for the message.  The new
         value of the flags is returned as if a FETCH of those flags was
         done.
```

Other bits that you may find relevant:

```
The currently defined data items that can be stored are:

      FLAGS <flag list>
         Replace the flags for the message (other than \Recent) with the
         argument.  The new value of the flags is returned as if a FETCH
         of those flags was done.

      FLAGS.SILENT <flag list>
         Equivalent to FLAGS, but without returning a new value.

      +FLAGS <flag list>
         Add the argument to the flags for the message.  The new value
         of the flags is returned as if a FETCH of those flags was done.

      +FLAGS.SILENT <flag list>
         Equivalent to +FLAGS, but without returning a new value.

      -FLAGS <flag list>
         Remove the argument from the flags for the message.  The new
         value of the flags is returned as if a FETCH of those flags was
         done.

      -FLAGS.SILENT <flag list>
         Equivalent to -FLAGS, but without returning a new value.
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Mark an email as `UNSEEN`. I thought the title was clear, I'll correct it just now.

Comment: So, did you try -FLAGS (\\Seen) ?  You're not using raw strings, so you need to escape the backslash.