# Mark a *single* IMAP message as unread

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, imaplib

I'm trying to manipulate IMAP flags on a single message to mark it unread, after fetching all the "UNREAD" messages and then iterating through them and fetching them.

I'm not entirely sure how to mark the messages unread/unseen on a single-message basis.  All I get is the message number, and I'm not sure how to store the UID properly to only affect the single message.

The [answer in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367611/python-imaplib-mark-email-as-unread-or-unseen/21479494#21479494) didn't appear to work, as it sets the *wrong* messages as 'unread'.  How do I go about setting a *single* mail message that I've fetched as 'unread' again?

---

I was asked to give more information.  While stripping out the specifics that are 'secret' here, this is the existing runtime that I've tried to implement, such that it attempts to process the message according to code rules, and stores the message numbers, etc., and attempts to set each message to "UNREAD" after storing the id and subject of the message in a pickle file, as anything that's been 'seen' during a run will be marked as 'read' on the server automatically, and not set to 'unread' status:

```
def main():
    conn = imaplib.IMAP4('SERVER')
    conn.login('username', 'passphrase')

    conn.select('inbox')
    (status, nums) = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')

    msgnums = map(int, nums[0].split())

    for i in msgnums:
        try:
            raw_msg = conn.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')

            raw_msg = conn.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')
            msg = email.message_from_string(raw_msg[1][0][1])
            body = "Date: %s\r\nSender: %s\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n" % (msg['Date'], msg['From'], msg['Subject'])
            msg_date = re.sub('/', '-', msg['Date']).replace(":", ".")
            fdate = re.sub('\s+', '_', msg_date).replace(",", "")
            print "Checking message: %s" % msg['Subject']

            if not msg['Subject']:
                continue  # fname = "unknown_msg%d_%s" % (i,fdate)
            elif msg['Subject'].lower().rfind('foobar') != -1:
                print "Subject match 'foobar', processing: %s" % msg['Subject']
                # We should have from the pickle an "observed" set of data, both subjects and message numbers.
                if msg['Subject'] in PICKLED_MESSAGES['observed']['subjects']:
                    print "Already handled this message, moving on to next item."
                    # Since this was already observed we let it be removed so things don't rerun it later.
                    # noinspection PyBroadException
                    try:
                        PICKLED_MESSAGES['observed']['subjects'].remove(msg['Subject'])
                        PICKLED_MESSAGES['observed']['msgnums'].remove(i)
                    except:
                        pass
                    continue
            else:
                continue

            # Do stuff with the message to store it in a special way on the filesystem

            # Note that we've now looked at the message, so next-run we can see
            # what was handled on the last run.
            PICKLED_MESSAGES['observed']['msgnums'].append(i)
            PICKLED_MESSAGES['observed']['subjects'].append(msg['Subject'])
            print "PICKLED:\n%s" % PICKLED_MESSAGES['observed']
            conn.uid('STORE', str(i), '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')
        except Exception:
            conn.uid('STORE', str(i), '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')
            PICKLED_MESSAGES['observed']['msgnums'].remove(i)
            PICKLED_MESSAGES['observed']['subjects'].remove(msg['Subject'])
            print "PICKLED:\n%s\n" % PICKLED_MESSAGES
        finally:
            # Store the pickle file so we can use it next run.
            cPickle.dump(PICKLED_MESSAGES, open('observed_msgs.pkl', 'wb'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # pre-runtime checks - is IMAP up, etc. run first, then this:

    # Initialize the PICKLED_MESSAGES data with pickle data or an empty
    # structure for the pickle.
    # noinspection PyBroadException
    try:
        PICKLED_MESSAGES = cPickle.load(open('observed_msgs.pkl', 'rb'))
    except Exception as e:
        PICKLED_MESSAGES = {
            'observed': {
                'msgnums': [],
                'subjects': [],
            },
        }

    # If all checks satisfied, continue and process the main() directives.
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print("CRITICAL    An unhandled error has occurred: %s" % str(e))
        exit()
```

However, it's *not* setting the correct message as 'unread; when using the methods I've seen suggested on the system.  So, I'm not entirely sure whether I'm not getting the UID of the message proper, or whether there's something else I'm missing doing here.

Comment: If it sets flags on a "wrong" message, you must be specifying a wrong message ID. Without any [details on what you're doing and what you're getting](/help/mcve), we cannot say anything else.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Details added, such as code, etc. and what i'm *observing* happening according to an IMAP check on the mailbox for what is or isn't unread posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I feel stupid today.

Apparently the message number being iterated over, and the UID of the message that `conn.uid(...)` expects are NOT necessarily the same number.  I figured out that one has to fetch the UID and do some post-fetch-processing to get just the UID to pass out.

---

***The Original Approach***

I was able to get the UID with the following, within that `for` loop above:

```py
for i in msgnums:
    # ...
    msg_uid = conn.fetch(i, 'UID')[1][0].split()[2].strip('()')
    # ...
```

This gave me the UID of the message, which `conn.uid` was expecting, rather than the plain message number.  I feel kinda stupid for not realizing this, but this fixed the issue, it seems.

---

***Updated Approach #1*** (thanks to [@Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442918/max) in comments)

I replaced all the search/fetch/store commands with UID-equivalents.

- `conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')` becomes `conn.uid('SEARCH', None, '(UNSEEN)')`
- `conn.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')` becomes `conn.uid('FETCH', i, '(RFC822)')`
- `conn.store(i, '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')` becomes `conn.uid('STORE', i, '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')`

---

***Updated Approach #2*** (inspired by #1, but going a step further)

I basically got tired of writing out the UID commands, but also need to apply similar UID-based functionality in another program that uses similar IMAP interfaces and commands.  Given this, I decided to write an `imaplib_extension.py` module that 'extends' the `imaplib`'s `IMAP4` and `IMAP4_SSL` functions, and overrides "search", "fetch" and "store" commands with the `uid` variants but otherwise keeps the "search", "fetch", and "store" commands as-is from `imaplib` but returns a different result-set that is based on UID functions instead.

This is what is in my `imaplib_extension.py` file, and I just import `IMAP4` or `IMAP4_SSL` from this module instead of from `imaplib` directly, and replace any `imaplib.IMAP4` and `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL` calls with just `IMAP4` or `IMAP4_SSL` calls later.  Therefore, no need to `import imaplib`, just `from imaplib import IMAP4` (or `IMAP4_SSL`, accordingly):

```py
import imaplib

class IMAP4(imaplib.IMAP4):
    def search(self, charset, *criteria):
        # conn.uid('SEARCH', charset, criteria)
        return self.uid('SEARCH', charset, " ".join(criteria))


    def fetch(self, message_set, message_parts):
        # conn.uid('FETCH', msgset, parts)
        return self.uid('FETCH', message_set, message_parts)

    def store(self, message_set, command, flags):
        # conn.uid('STORE', msg_uid, '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')
        return self.uid('STORE', message_set, command, flags)


# noinspection PyPep8Naming
class IMAP4_SSL(imaplib.IMAP4_SSL):
    def search(self, charset, *criteria):
        # conn.uid('SEARCH', charset, criteria)
        return self.uid('SEARCH', charset, " ".join(criteria))

    def fetch(self, message_set, message_parts):
        # conn.uid('FETCH', msgset, parts)
        return self.uid('FETCH', message_set, message_parts)

    def store(self, message_set, command, flags):
        # conn.uid('STORE', msg_uid, '-FLAGS', '(\Seen)')
        return self.uid('STORE', message_set, command, flags)
```

I much prefer using this extension of `imaplib`, because the command structure remains *identical* to the existing commands, but properly works with UIDs instead of 'message numbers' that might not be UIDs.

---

***Updated Approach #3***

After realizing that I've needed this in *other* Python applications, I got off my butt and published [`imaplibext` on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imaplibext), which basically is an improved and fleshed out version of approach #2 above.  It does, however, have far better error handling, and the ability to actually specify timeout for an IMAP connection socket.  This is an improvement as you can't directly do that for `imaplib.IMAP4` or `imaplib.IMAP4_SSL`, and among other things is essentially a drop-in replacement for `imaplib` (though at its core it still uses `imaplib`).

The code for this also exists at [GitHub](https://github.com/teward/imaplibext) for general use and improvement suggestions and issue reports.

Comment: Or always use UIDs, with: conn.uid('SEARCH', ...) and conn.uid('FETCH', ..) and conn.uid('STORE').  By doing `UID SEARCH` you won't ever have sequence numbers and have to translate between them and UIDs.

Comment: @Max Would that work with "Fetch all unread messages"?  Such that we need to use "SEARCH" or something and be given the correct UID of messages for fetching everything?

Comment: conn.uid('SEARCH', ...) works exactly the same as conn.search(...) except it returns UIDs instead of message sequence numbers.  Same as uid('FETCH', ...) vs fetch(...) and uid('STORE') vs store()

Comment: @Max Thanks to your recommendations, UID-based functions work *great*.  it also led to me extending `imaplib` to replace the fetch/store/search functions with UID-based ones, even though I don't have to (I would rather be able to drop in-place a new module that 'overrides' standard functionality and still works, than not...)